# Rails 6 Docker run rake db:seed command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, kubernetes, docker-compose

I am working on rails application and it uses Docker and Kubernetes.

I do not know Docker and Kubernetes and I need to run the seed file on the production server but it's not working.

Following is my Docker file

```
FROM ruby:2.6.5-alpine

RUN apk update
RUN apk add bash build-base libxml2-dev libxslt-dev postgresql postgresql-dev nodejs vim 
yarn libc6-compat curl

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY template-app/Gemfile* ./
RUN gem install bundler && bundle config https://gem.abc.io/xyz/ nvHuX- 
OXxLY2OpiQkFVfgnYgd4ertyufdds
RUN bundle install
#RUN bundle exec rake db:seed(not working)

COPY template-app/ .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["bundle", "exec", "rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0", "-p", "3000"]
```

In the Docker file, I have added RUN bundle exec rake db:seed but it's not working and my build is not passed(deployed)

I am using postgres database.

I do not have docker composer file.

Thanks.

Edit:

I got the following error when I write rake db:migrate in the docker file

```
Removing intermediate container 3634d992e850
---> 1bd575429f8e
Step 9/12 : RUN bundle exec rake db:seed
---> Running in f5d8c63f7db7
rake aborted!
No Rakefile found (looking for: rakefile, Rakefile, rakefile.rb, Rakefile.rb)
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-13.0.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bundle/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bundle/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Edit

I have added following code in dockerfile

```
RUN yarn install --check-files
RUN bundle exec rake db:seed
```

I am able to run the seed command but get the following error

[image]

Edit

My application directory structure

[image]

Here my rails app is in template-app folder and dockerfile is outside the folder

Database.yml file

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV["RAILS_DB_POOL"] || ENV['RAILS_MAX_THREADS'] || 5 %>
  idle_timeout: <%= ENV["RAILS_IDLE_CONNECTION"] ||  60 %>
  port: <%= ENV['RAILS_DATABASE_PORT'] || 5432 %>

# For details on connection pooling, see Rails configuration guide
# https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
development:
  <<: *default
  adapter: postgresql
  database: <%= ENV['TEMPLATEAPP_DATABASE'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['TEMPLATEAPP_DATABASE_USER'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['TEMPLATEAPP_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
  host: <%= ENV['TEMPLATE_DATABASE_HOSTNAME'] %>

test:
  <<: *default
  adapter: postgresql
  database: <%= ENV['TEMPLATEAPP_DATABASE'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['TEMPLATEAPP_DATABASE_USER'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['TEMPLATEAPP_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
  host: <%= ENV['TEMPLATE_DATABASE_HOSTNAME'] %>


production:
  <<: *default
  adapter: postgresql
  database: <%= ENV['TEMPLATEAPP_DATABASE'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['TEMPLATEAPP_DATABASE_USER'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['TEMPLATEAPP_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
  host: <%= ENV['TEMPLATE_DATABASE_HOSTNAME'] %>
```

Comment: Well I will do is comment lines of your db:seed command and then run instance and use bash to see inside instance why it is not working. or you can check by `docker logs`

Comment: @KamalPanhwar thanks for the comment pls check my edit

Comment: `COPY template-app/ .` move it above `rake db:migrate` command the error will change and will complain about postgres.

Answer (score 2):

Well there are lot of things going on in your Dockerfile, first you are installing postgresql but you are not doing its initial configuration. Normal we use docker-compose file and use pre build postgresql for it with following docker image

```
  db:
    image: postgres:11
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - '../../tmp/data/pg11:/var/lib/postgresql/data:cached'
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ''
      POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust
      PGDATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
```

Now another issue is you are using rails 6 mean you have to run yarn to install all packages. so I also added following line

```
RUN yarn install --check-files
```

The other issue is you are running your db migration before copying your project. you can use following Dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:2.6.5-alpine

RUN apk update
RUN apk add bash build-base libxml2-dev libxslt-dev postgresql postgresql-contrib postgresql-dev nodejs vim yarn libc6-compat curl

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY template-app/Gemfile* ./
RUN gem install bundler
# RUN gem install bundler && bundle config https://gem.abc.io/xyz/ nvHuX- 
RUN bundle install

COPY template-app/ .
RUN yarn install --check-files
RUN bundle exec rake db:seed

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["bundle", "exec", "rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0", "-p", "3000"]
```

But as I told you due to postgresql it wont' work, till you setup postgres and take consideration using its credentials in your config/database.yml file.

Please use following format

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV["RAILS_DB_POOL"] || ENV['RAILS_MAX_THREADS'] || 5 %>
  idle_timeout: <%= ENV["RAILS_IDLE_CONNECTION"] ||  60 %>
  port: <%= ENV['RAILS_DATABASE_PORT'] || 5432 %>

# For details on connection pooling, see Rails configuration guide
# https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
development:
  <<: *default
  adapter: postgresql
  database: <%= ENV['TEMPLATEAPP_DATABASE'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['TEMPLATEAPP_DATABASE_USER'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['TEMPLATEAPP_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
  host: <%= ENV['TEMPLATE_DATABASE_HOSTNAME'] %>

test:
  <<: *default
  adapter: postgresql
  database: <%= ENV['TEMPLATEAPP_DATABASE'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['TEMPLATEAPP_DATABASE_USER'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['TEMPLATEAPP_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
  host: <%= ENV['TEMPLATE_DATABASE_HOSTNAME'] %>
```

Comment: @kamakpanhwar can you pls check the last edit as I am getting error in seed command running. can you suggest any solution for this?

Comment: Can yo share yoru config/database.yml file as seem one of config field is nil instead of value

Comment: Pls check my latest edit. I have a somewhat different directory structure as I am using Kubernetes and docker compare to the traditional rails app. Also, I do not have a docker composer file.

Comment: You db format is this?  it is wrong you need to add proper indention! yml need indentions. I added that one in answer. Also you have to create new question so it can be helpful to other people, and even did not select any answer you need to select answers if they really help you

Comment: I know, it's not the same indentation. my file is with proper indentation as you given.

Comment: pls check as I change the indentation as it is in my code.

Comment: Please create new question, error is telling you that you can't connect to postgresql I will again ssh to my application_docker and try to echo $TEMPLATE_DATABASE_HOSTNAME and see what value comes, normally in docker you put db as host instead of localhost! sorry I realy don't know much about Kubernet and neither did anything on it. New question will draw attention and someone will help you.